# Confluent HDFS Sink Connector: How to configure custom hadoop user and group?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

We are currently using Confluent HDFS Sink Connector platform within docker container to write data from Kafka(separate Kafka cluster) to HDFS(separate Hadoop cluster). By default the connector platform writes data to HDFS with ***root*** user and ***wheel*** group. 
How can i configure connector to use a specific hadoop user/group ? Is there an environment variable I need to set in docker ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java process in the Docker container runs as root.

You need to either make your own container with your own user account or run the Connect Workers as a different Unix account in some other way.

You could try setting `HADOOP_IDENT_USER` or `HADOOP_USER_NAME` environment variables, but I think these are only pulled by the Hadoop scripts, not the Java API

Keep in mind that user accounts in Hadoop don't really matter if you're not using a Kerberized cluster

Comment: Setting the HADOOP_USER_NAME=<user> env variable did the trick, however it would be good if the hadoop user can be provided at the task level(like a parameter in hdfs sink connector properties file). We use kubernetes to manage the confluent connector platform. Since we want two different hadoop users to write hdfs files, we have to tell kubernetes to start two different replication controllers passing different hadoop user environment variables and have to expose 2 different ports for submitting the connector hdfs properties. I am not sure if kubernetes has a different way to handle this.

Comment: I have never used k8s. Your better option would be to build your own internal "company docker images" using a private registry and such, then customizing from there. That also allows you to easily patch the Confluent Docker images to add the PR's that have been sitting around for months.